# How to generate XML file from HTML form DOM FiELDSETS

Tags: javascript, html, fieldset

```
i want to generate XML string from HTML form  using Javascript.
****************** HTML Form ********************
```

```html
<form id="demo1"><div><div name="XMLDIV" id="XMLDIV"><fieldset name="COUNTRY" id="COUNNTRY">
    <legend>COUNTRY</legend>
    <fieldset name="STATE" id="STATE">
        <legend>STATE</legend>
        <label>AP</label>
        <input type="text" value="Andhra" /><br />
        <label>KR</label><input type="text" value="Karnataka" /><br />
        <fieldset name="DISTRICT" id="DISTRICT">
            <legend>DISTRICT</legend>
            <label>CT</label>
            <input type="text" value="CHIT" /><br />
            <label>VJ</label><input type="text" value="VIJAYA" /><br />
       
        </fieldset>
       
    </fieldset>
</fieldset></div></div>
</form>
```

From the HTML form need to get DOM object, create element nodes based on fieldset id and generate teh child nodes. need to generate following xml format 12vija